# use apt-cache to print package names

Tags: apt

Is there a way to print the name of only those packages that consists of certain keywords in their description?

Specifically, I am looking for packages that does not contains php in the description.

Something like -

```
apt-cache search --full 'php' | grep -e '^Package :'
```

will print packages with php in their description.

However, I want to negate the result.

Comment: why not `grep -E '[^php]'`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for , did you need to exclude just the package description? or you need to print only one package without description ?

Comment: Try `apt-cache search --names-only '[^.*php.*]' | grep -Ev 'php'` for package names only, or `apt-cache search --full '[^.*php.*]' | grep -Ev 'php'` for full package details.

Comment: I have posted an answer , please correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @GAD3R yes, you misunderstood. As written in the question, I am looking for all packageS ( not a single package ). Also, the packageS should not have the keyword php in their full desciption. GeorgeUdosen is close, yet it does not print all the package names.

Comment: You say it doesn't list all the packages how so?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I used to achieve this are:

1. For only package names:

   ```
   apt-cache pkgnames | grep -iv '.*php.*'
   ```
2. With full package description:

   ```
   apt-cache pkgnames | grep -iv '.*php.*' | xargs -L 1 apt-cache search --full
   ```

More information:

- `grep -iv '.*php.*'`: neagtes results for ones containing `foo-php-bar`
- `xargs -L 1 apt-cache search --full`: passes the grep result to `apt-cache` comand to print full package descriptions.

Note: The last command spues out a lot of stuff.

Comment: Can you please describe the second command? What is '[^.*php.*]'  doing here?

Comment: It does the same thing as the first command but this time the full package description for non-php packages are returned.

Comment: As written in the question, I am looking for packages that does not contain the word php. According to your solution, it looks like, the command return packages that has the word php and then you negate the word php through grep. It doesnt make much sense.

Comment: What sense are we talking here, or better, insist on a particular solution. I see you used grep in yours so why the `makes no sense`?

Comment: see, the question is -  if it is possible to print all the packages that DOES NOT CONTAIN the word "php" in their package name as well as description? But your solution is broken, because it is looking  for packages that CONTAINS the word php. Quote - `[^.*php.*]: targets names like foo-php-bar, foophpbar, etc. The ^.* is regex for the line begins with foo`. My use of grep is to just list the lines with the word Package. The use of grep in my example has nothing to do with listing packages related to php or !php.

Comment: Ok let me adjust it

Comment: @infoclogged please see if this helps so I can update the answer `apt-cache pkgnames | grep -iv '.*php.*' | xargs -L 1 apt-cache search --full`

Comment: Dont worry and thank you.. I was looking for a simple solution where I can pass the regex to apt-cache using negative lookup or so. I have already found a solution myself that also works on multiple pipes.

Comment: Please post that as an answer!